# turbo_stream_from with multi targets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo

Is there a way to broadcast a content on several locations?
I would like to update an image which is visible on 2 places of my page.

How can i do, as my frame should have a uniq id. Should I call the broadcast method 2 times and use 2 differents targets on my frame?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your exact answer but in this page video will help you to understand turbo_stream_form https://hotwired.dev/#screencast